# Calling robocopy from wix customaction errors out

Tags: wix, custom-action, robocopy

I have a wix custom action

```
<CustomAction Id="BaselineSync_Cmd" Property="BaselineSync" Execute="immediate"
    Value="&quot;robocopy&quot; &quot;[SI_BUP]&quot; &quot;[SI_PROD]&quot; /PURGE" />
<CustomAction Id="BaselineSync" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec" Execute="deferred" Return="ignore" Impersonate="no"/>
<CustomAction Id="RoboCopy_Cmd" Property="RoboCopy" Execute="immediate"
    Value="&quot;robocopy&quot; &quot;[INSDIR]&quot; [SI_PROD]" />
<CustomAction Id="RoboCopy" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec" Execute="deferred" Return="ignore" Impersonate="no"/>
```

The earlier robocopy command works for me but not the second.
While installing, I pass the values of SI_BUP, INSDIR and SI_PROD via the commandline. Something like this: INSDIR=C:\testing\CONTENT SI_BUP=C:\testing\BACKUP SI_PROD=C:\testing\PROD /qn /l*v install.log

Log from first custom action:

```
MSI (s) (74:88) [15:00:52:118]: Executing op: CustomActionSchedule(Action=BaselineSync,ActionType=3137,Source=BinaryData,Target=CAQuietExec,CustomActionData="robocopy" "C:\testing\BACKUP" "C:\testing\PROD" /PURGE /e)

CAQuietExec:  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CAQuietExec:     ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows                              
CAQuietExec:  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CAQuietExec:  
CAQuietExec:    Started : Thu Jun 19 15:00:52 2014
CAQuietExec:  
CAQuietExec:     Source : C:\testing\BACKUP\
CAQuietExec:       Dest : C:\testing\PROD\
```

Log from the second custom action:

```
MSI (s) (74:88) [15:00:52:190]: Executing op: CustomActionSchedule(Action=RoboCopy,ActionType=3137,Source=BinaryData,Target=CAQuietExec,CustomActionData="robocopy" "C:\testing\CONTENT\" "C:\testing\PROD" /e)

CAQuietExec:  
CAQuietExec:  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CAQuietExec:     ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows                              
CAQuietExec:  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CAQuietExec:  
CAQuietExec:    Started : Thu Jun 19 15:00:52 2014
CAQuietExec:  
CAQuietExec:     Source : C:\testing\CONTENT" C:\testing\PROD \e\
CAQuietExec:       Dest -
```

I am not able to figure out what I should be doing such that robocopy works fine. I'm not looking at a batch approach for making this happen... just customaction. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<CustomAction Id="BaselineSync_Cmd" Property="BaselineSync" Execute="immediate" 
    Value="&quot;robocopy&quot; &quot;[SI_BUP]&quot; &quot;[SI_PROD]&quot; /PURGE /e" />
<CustomAction Id="BaselineSync" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec" Execute="deferred" Return="ignore" Impersonate="no"/>
<CustomAction Id="RoboCopy_Cmd" Property="RoboCopy" Execute="immediate"
    Value="&quot;robocopy&quot; &quot;[INSDIR]$(var.AppName)&quot; &quot;[SI_PROD]&quot; /e" />
<CustomAction Id="RoboCopy" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec" Execute="deferred" Return="ignore" Impersonate="no"/>
```

A little change on the second customaction as shown above -RoboCopy_Cmd where I added $(var.AppName) which is set in the msbuild file from where this customaction is being called and a slight change in the commandline argument achieved the desired result.

The commandline now looks like:

```
INSDIR=C:\testing\CONTENT SI_BUP=C:\testing\MyProd SI_PROD=C:\testing\PROD\MyProd
```

In the msbuild file AppName is set as:

```
<AppName>MyProd</AppName>
```

and INSDIR is the location where the product is installed. So the contents are installed to `C:\testing\CONTENT\MyProd`

Answer (score 0):

There is a trailing backslash in the `[INSDIR]` variable, as evidenced by this portion of the log on the second CA:

```
"robocopy" "C:\testing\CONTENT\" "C:\testing\PROD"
```

Instead of `C:\testing\CONTENT\` you need `C:\Testing\CONTENT`. This is essentially a Robocopy syntax error.

Comment: Thanks Snixtor. That is what robocopy is showing via the log, however when I am passing the values via commandline I have no such trailling backslash.